# How can I create a table as matrix with primefaces (3D Table somehow)?

Tags: java, jsf-2, primefaces

I have found the same question [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16350122/primefaces-3-dimensional-datatable/), and I tried to do the same for my project, but I can't get the results, can anyone check my code below and tell me where have I make a mistake.
What I want to do is to get a Table where columns are the aircrafts and the rows are the work packages of each aircraft and the cells are the jobs in each work package of each aircraft.
the XHTML is:

```
<h:form id="globalreport">
  <p:layout>
   <p:layoutUnit position="north">
 <p:selectOneMenu id="model" value="#{userInterfaceMB.model}">
   <f:selectItem itemLabel="All models" itemValue="" />
   <f:selectItems value="#{userInterfaceMB.getAllAvailableModels()}" />
   <p:ajax update="aircraftTable"listener="#{userInterfaceMB.handleModelChange()}" />
 </p:selectOneMenu>
   </p:layoutUnit>

<p:layoutUnit position="center">
<p:dataTable id="aircraftTable" var="workPackageId" 
             value="# {userInterfaceMB.workPackagesIds}" rowIndexVar="rowIdx">
           <p:column headerText="" styleClass="ui-widget-header">
                <h:outputText value="#{workPackageId}" />
                 </p:column>
                <p:columns var="aircraftId" value="#  
                                               {userInterfaceMB.aircraftsIds}"
                         headerText="#{aircraftId}"   
                                                 columnIndexVar="colIdx">
        <ui:repeat value="#{userInterfaceMB.myJobs[rowIdx][colIdx]}"  
                               var="myJob">
                         <p:panel>
                <h:outputText value="#{myJob}" />
             </p:panel>
        </ui:repeat>
    </p:columns
</p:dataTable>
</p:layoutUnit> 
</p:layout>
</h:form>
</h:body>
```

And here's my ManagedBean:

```
@ManagedBean(name="userInterfaceMB")
@SessionScoped
@ComponentScan("com.")
public class UserInterfaceBean implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    //TODO Autowired is not working, get it to work
    @Autowired
    private DBDataManipulatorService dbDataManipulatorService;

    private int aircraftId;
    private String type;
    private String model;
    private List<String> workPackagesIds;
    private List<Integer> aircraftsIds;
    private ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<MyJob>>> myJobs;
    private List<Aircraft> aircrafts; 


    public ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<MyJob>>> getMyJobs() {
        return myJobs;
    }

    public void setMyJobs(ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<MyJob>>> myJobs) {
        this.myJobs = myJobs;
    }

    public List<Integer> getAircraftsIds() {
        return aircraftsIds;
    }

    public void setAircraftsIds(List<Integer> aircraftsIDs) {
        this.aircraftsIds = aircraftsIDs;
    }

    public UserInterfaceBean(){
        //Because the Autowire is not working
        WebApplicationContext ctx =  
                FacesContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance());
        dbDataManipulatorService = ctx.getBean(DBDataManipulatorService.class);

    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void Init() {

        aircrafts = new ArrayList<Aircraft>();
        aircrafts = dbDataManipulatorService.findAllAircrafts();

    }

    public List<Aircraft> getAircrafts() {
        if(aircrafts==null){
            aircrafts = dbDataManipulatorService.findAllAircrafts();
        }

        return aircrafts;
    }

    public void setAircrafts(List<Aircraft> aircrafts) {
        this.aircrafts = aircrafts;
    }

    public DBDataManipulatorService getDBDataManipulatorService() {

        return dbDataManipulatorService;
    }

    public void setDBDataManipulatorService(DBDataManipulatorService   
                                                dbDataManipulatorService) {

    }

    public int getAircraftId() {
        return aircraftId;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public String getModel() {
        return model;
    }


    public List<String> getWorkPackagesIds() {
        return workPackagesIds;
    }



    public void setAircraftId(int aircraftId) {
        this.aircraftId = aircraftId;
    }


    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }


    public void setModel(String model) {
        this.model = model;
    }


    public void setWorkPackagesIds(List<String> workPackageIds) {
        this.workPackagesIds = workPackageIds;
    }

    public List<String> getAllAvailableModels(){

        return  dbDataManipulatorService.findAllAvailableAircraftsModels();
    }

    public void handleModelChange(){

        List<Aircraft> aircrafts =   
                               dbDataManipulatorService.findAllAircraftsByModel(model);

        setAircrafts(aircrafts); 
        List<Integer> aircraftsIds = new ArrayList<Integer>(); 

        for(Aircraft aircraft:aircrafts){

            int aircraftId = aircraft.getAircraftId();
            aircraftsIds.add(aircraftId);               
        }
        setAircraftsIds(aircraftsIds);
        getDistinctWorkPackageId(model);
        updateMyJobs();
    }

    public List<WorkPackage> getAllAvailableWorkPackesByAircraftModel(String model){

        List<WorkPackage> workpackages = new ArrayList<WorkPackage>();

        workpackages = dbDataManipulatorService.getWorkPackagesByAircraftModel(model);

        return workpackages;
    }

    public void getDistinctWorkPackageId(String model){

        List<String> workPackagesIds = new ArrayList<String>();
        List<WorkPackage> workPackages = 
                                  getAllAvailableWorkPackesByAircraftModel(model);

        for(WorkPackage workPackage: workPackages){

            String workPackageId = workPackage.getWorkPackageId();

            if (!workPackagesIds.contains(workPackageId)){

                workPackagesIds.add(workPackageId);
            }       
        }
        setWorkPackagesIds(workPackagesIds);
    }

    public void updateMyJobs(){
        ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<MyJob>>> myJobs = 
                                                 new ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<MyJob>>>();

                Map<Integer, Aircraft> aircraftsMap = getAircraftsMap();

        int aircraftId = 0;
        String workPackageId = null;

        for (int i = 0; i < aircraftsIds.size(); i++) {

            aircraftId = aircraftsIds.get(i);

            if (aircraftsMap.containsKey(aircraftId)){

                Aircraft aircraft = aircraftsMap.get(aircraftId);

                Map<String, WorkPackage> workPackagesMap = 
                                                         aircraft.getWorkPackagesMap();

                for(int j=0; j<workPackagesIds.size();j++){

                    workPackageId = workPackagesIds.get(j);

                    if(workPackagesMap.containsKey(workPackageId)){

                        WorkPackage workPackage = 
                                                          workPackagesMap.get(workPackageId);

                        List<MyJob> jobsMap = 
                                               (List<MyJob>)workPackage.getJobsMap().values();                      

                        for(MyJob myJob:jobsMap){

                            myJobs.get(i).get(j).add(myJob);
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
        }

        setMyJobs(myJobs);
    }


    private  Map<Integer, Aircraft> getAircraftsMap(){

        Map<Integer, Aircraft> aircraftsMap = new HashMap<Integer, Aircraft>();

        for(Aircraft aircraft: aircrafts){

            aircraftsMap.put(aircraft.getAircraftId(), aircraft);
        }

        return aircraftsMap;

    }

}
```

Please, a quick help is very appreciated. what I want to have is below:

```
+--------------+--------------------------+--------------------------+-------------+------
|              |  Aircraft1               |  Aircraft2               |  ...... ....
+--------------+--------------------------+--------------------------+-------------+------
|              | +-------+----------+     | +-------+----------+     |
|              | |jobId1 |jobstatus |     | |jobId1 |jobstatus |     |  
|              | +-------+----------+     | +-------+----------+     |
| Workpackage1 | |jobId2 |jobstatus |     | |jobId2 |jobstatus |     |
|              | +-------+----------+     | +-------+----------+     |
|              | |jobId3 |jobstatus |     |                          |
|              | +-------+----------+     |                          |
+--------------+--------------------------+--------------------------+-------------------
|              | +-------+----------+     | +-------+----------+     |
|              | |jobId1 |jobstatus |     | |jobId1 |jobstatus |     |  
|              | +-------+----------+     | +-------+----------+     |
| Workpackage2 |                          | |jobId2 |jobstatus |     |
|              | +-------+----------+     | +-------+----------+     |
|              | |jobId3 |jobstatus |     |                          |
|              | +-------+----------+     |                          |
+--------------+--------------------------+--------------------------+-------------------
  ....
```